# Knockout mapping plugin: reload data with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I want to display the detail of my user data within a Bootstrap modal. I load the data with AJAX, and bind them to a Knockout ViewModel with the `knockout mapping plugin`.

This is working very well, but as soon as I load the user data more than once, I always see following message:

```
Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

**Knockout ViewModel:**

```
function UserViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.loadUserData = function(userId) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/user/loadUserDetail.htm",
            data: {"userId": userId},
            success : function(response) {
                self.userHelper = ko.mapping.fromJSON(response);
                ko.applyBindings(self); 
                $("#user-dialog").modal('show');
            },
            error : function(e) {
                showErrorBox('Error: ' + e.status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the data down like you are, but once you have it, use var jsonToJsObj = $.parseJSON(jsonResult) to get a js object, you then use ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonToJsObj) and that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I receive the same message as before.

Comment: success : function(response) {
   var jsonToJsObj = $.parseJSON(response);
   self.userHelper = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonToJsObj); 
    ko.applyBindings(self); 
    $("#user-dialog").modal('show');
},